# Dumb Guards Attack Me for No Reason

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I swear I didn't do anything. The Guards of Whiterun attack me for no reason. I don't know why. I don't have any bounty. Can anyone help me? This has happened in Solitude the first time I went there, but the guards stopped attacking me. Oh yeah, I'm not a Vampire

Comment: Why was this question closed? seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Are you on the thief group?

Comment: The reason why you might get attacked in Solitude is because you were at the execution interrupting it which causes guards to attack, but no bounty. I fond this out. I don't know any similar cause in Whiterun.